# Is there such a thing as pattern matching in typless languages

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Pattern matching is very popular these days in functional programming. I am using JavaScript and do not remember any example of pattern matching in this language. Pattern matching seems to be dependent on type inference and seem unapplicable to JavaScript and other typeless languages (Python?). So my question is am I right here? Or some pattern matching could be used or implemented in typeless languages?

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: @NinaScholz, you seem to have this question rephrased.

Comment: Take a look at this repo https://github.com/bramstein/funcy

Comment: I don't understand why pattern matching would depend on type inference. It depends on what you mean by "typeless", but Erlang's pattern matching is very nice - you can even match on binary data. You can implement matching yourself in Lisp and Scheme (or use libraries). Prolog also springs to mind. (And by "these days" I assume you mean "for the last decades".)

Comment: Prolog and Erlang have native syntax for pattern matching.  Lisp systems have long had pattern matching macros as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pattern matching is orthogonal to typing (dynamic or static).

Erlang is a good example of a dynamically typed language that relies heavily on [pattern matching](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/patterns.html).  In fact, all assignment in Erlang is a pattern match.

So, yes, pattern matching can be implemented in dynamically typed languages like JavaScript.